# Treat specific space as character when reading file

Tags: sas

There´s in SAS a intuitive & easy way of reading the space
between 2 numbers without skipping to the next column.

I have a dataset with the following structure.
The following code reads correctly every line except
the one I show in the example case.

My expect output would be as follows:

```
|A     |B     |C    |D    |E   |
|------|----- |-----|---- |  ---|
|33    |2 2   |66   |89   |99  |

data try1;
input A 1-3 B  7-9 C 14-16  D 17-19  E 24-25;
cards;
33 1  2 2  66 7 8988 9 99
;
```

Treat space as character when having multiple spaces

Comment: The string '2 2' is not a number. Do you want the variable B to be a character variable? If so add a $ between the B and the range of columns in the input statement.

Comment: @Tom Okey, I did not see it that way before. TY!